# Webstorm 10 Code Completion not working with AngularJS controllerAs syntax

Tags: angularjs, webstorm, code-completion

I'm trying out WebStorm because it claims to have superior code completion when working with AngularJS projects.  I'm using version 10.0.2 and ran into a code completion issue already using the AngularJS seed project.

I’m trying to use the controllerAs syntax to specify the controller viewmodel’s name inside the $routeProvider as follows.

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.view1', ['ngRoute'])

.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/view1', {
    templateUrl: 'view1/view1.html',
    controller: 'View1Ctrl',
    controllerAs: 'vm'
  });
}])

.controller('View1Ctrl', [function() {
      var vm = this;
      vm.hello = 'Hello World';
}]);
```

[Controller & Route Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CSRJ.png)

However, inside the template html I get a “unresolved variable or type” warning. (a squiggly line under vm)

```
<p>This is the partial for view 1.</p>
<div>{{vm.hello}}</div>
```

[HTML warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RC59D.png)

But the page loads just fine when I run it

I'd show the pictorial proof but I need more rep first:^)

Again, I’m just using the OOTB AngularJS Project that is listed as one of the base templates to create a new WebStorm project so I would expect everything is already configured properly for Angular to work properly.  I’ve also watched a Pluralsight video where this kind of code completion seemed to work, although it was in WebStorm 9 not 10.

I checked and I have the AngularJS Plugin enabled.  I also tried downloading the typsescript community stub Javascript Library for angularjs, but it didn’t seem to help.  I generated the project using "Generating an AngularJS Application Stub" which according to the docs should give me Angular support.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should provide the code; not a screenshot of the code; as well as what you're trying to do with it. Pictures are helpful, but if those links die, no one will be able to tell what you're trying to do.

Comment: Have you followed "Installing AngularJS Manually" here https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/using-angularjs.html? Also, I seem to remember that you need to have angular.js or angular.min.js somewhere in you project folder, although I could be wrong.

Comment: Good call @GeorgeStocker

Comment: @camden_kid I did the "Generating an AngularJS Application Stub" approach which is supposed to work after running an "npm install".  I tried adding the angular.js file to the Javascript Library set in Settings, but no dice.  Does the controllerAs example above work for you in your environment when you performed the "Installing Angular JS Manually" set of steps?  Are you on WebStorm 10 as well?  Thanks!

Comment: I was using WebStorm last year and currently using PHPStorm (which, I assume, has the same AngularJS integration) and didn't come across your problem. I'll set up a project using your code and see what happens...

Comment: @camden_kid awesome, thanks!  I just realized I did forget to mention that the seed project comes with angular 1.2.x specified in the bower.json file.  I did update that to 1.3.x just to get the latest/greatest.  I wouldn't think that would matter, but wanted to mention it just in case it does.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Do you actually have the file angular.js or angular.min.js somewhere *within* the directory structure of your project?

Comment: @camden_kid it exists in the project at angularTest\app\bower_components\angular\angular.js .  I tried pasting a secong copy of angular.js to angularTest\app in case the bower folder was somehow getting excluded but it didnt seem to make a difference:(

Comment: If I were you, I'd update to the newest version. I just did the same thing you did today and didn't get squiggly lines. It it might be in the updated version, or you don't have something right in your code which we cannot see.

Answer (score 4):

You can work around this by adding jsdoc comment

```
/**
 * @name vm
 * @type View1Ctrl
 */
```

Comment: This works nice! Unfortunately you can't rely on convenient 'vm' everywhere anymore... maybe it's a good thing.

Answer (score 2):

I heard from JetBrains support that both 'controllerAs syntax' and  'Router support' are both under development still and are planned to be improved upon in the future.

If like me you want to support these efforts you can vote for them here:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-11175

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-10654

Answer (score 0):

--- Currently in Webstorm 2016 v.3 ---

In your wrapper element for the directive, you can be redundant and use attribute

```
ng-controller="vm as vm"
```

then all these squiggles will go back into the hole darcula hole they belong...can't bring myself to do it, personally...but it does make them disappear.

No additional suggestions...nothing useful...only absence of squiggle.